# How can I disable restoring Workgroups for Windows (for Emacs) on startup?

Tags: window

I'm trying to figure out how I can disable the restoring of windows when I start Emacs.

I've asked the project, but it seems this project is not maintained anymore.

[Workgroups for Windows (for Emacs)](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el/issues/55)

I've seen some references that it can be disabled, but I can't actually find the command to do so.

Comment: If you still have the references you mention, you should add them to the question.